# Change wp_get_archives by ACF

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display an archive of post by year, so year appear and when click, see all posts from that specific year. Problem is I want them to be displayed not by `post_date` (the default behavior), but by a custom date (a custom field made with ACF). 
Is there any hook to change the `wp_get_archives` function to take posts by ACF?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar requirement in a project. We found it easiest to get the value from the datepicker and apply it as the `post_date` using the `wp_post_update()` hook.

```
function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {

    // get new value
    $theDate = get_field('post-date', $post_id, false);
    $theDate = date_create_from_format('Ymd', $theDate);
    $theDate = date_format($theDate, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $my_post = array(
      'ID'           => $post_id,
      'post_date'   => $theDate,
    );
    // do something

    // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
    remove_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post');

    // update the post, which calls save_post again
    wp_update_post( $my_post );

    // re-hook this function
    add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post');

}

// run after ACF saves the $_POST['acf'] data
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);
```

The above code snippet was provided by James on the ACF support forums, but worked for us. One drawback to this solution is that if the date is in the future, the post will get scheduled instead of published.